# What does the method "InitTableColumns" of the "Database" class in the "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" library do?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

In the "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" nuget package there's a "Database" class which has a "InitTableColumns" method. As any method in said library this one hasn't got a summary. More bizzare is that there isn't ANY mention of in it The Internet (yes, seriously).

Especially the [MSDN Database class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0) page.

So, does anyone know what it does?

Comment: Sounds like some internal hoopla that was accidentally exposed. Why not take an IL decompiler like ILSpy to the thing and see?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, sounds awesome but I'm afraid I have no idea how. :D

Comment: Build/publish your application (using the package), navigate to the `bin` folder, find the SMO DLL and drag it into ILSpy. Find the method, right-click, expand "called by" to see what part of the code calls it and why (my guess would be a constructor or other init method somewhere). I'd do it myself but I lack access to a VS instance at the moment. If the method isn't documented you're almost certainly not actually meant to call it yourself and are supposed to pretend it's not there, so the decompiling is strictly for fun and profit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, actually, like I said/wrote in my question, NONE of the methods or properties in the SMO library are documented. Both in VS and in MSDN.

Comment: I suspect this is an artifact/holdover from being migrated to a new package. I'm almost positive the individual member documentation was present for older versions (when SMO was included with SQL Server itself) -- but unfortunately, Microsoft is really good at making old documentation disappear as if it never even existed, so I can't back up my claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking undocumented methods are best avoided :)

If you want to decompile it you can use a program like DotPeek (from JetBrains) or ILSpy.

Once the decompiling program is installed, you need to find the dll that you want to decompile. Decompiling will take the compiled .NET code and convert it back into C# that should be easier to read (note that is not always the case).

Finding the dll is easy, you either pull it from the `bin` folder of the compiled code, or you can browse find the path to it by finding the dependency `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects` in the VS solution explorer drop-down, right-clicking on the dependency, clicking "properties", and copying the path that shows in the property window.

Now that you have the path to the dll, you use the decompiler to open the dll at that path and decompile it. Once decompiled, the decompiler program will let you browse the namespaces, classes, and methods contained in the dll.

this is what it shows me about `InitTableColumns()`

```
public void InitTableColumns()
{
    this.InitChildLevel((Urn)"Table", (ScriptingPreferences)null, false);
    this.InitChildLevel((Urn)"Table/Column", (ScriptingPreferences)null, false);
}
```

Which then leads me on a wild goose chase through the code trying to understand how this library is implemented!